# Using TSQL ROUND in nHibernate

Tags: t-sql, fluent-nhibernate, rounding

How can I use the TSQL function ROUND in nHibernate.
I know SQL-functions are accessible via Projects.SQLFunction(..), but I don't see how I can add the desired precision as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this Ayende post](http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate) is what you're looking for